# Implementing a binary search tree

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement a binary search tree that holds an inventory of ordered stock. The stocked item attributes are stored in nodes as such:

```
typedef struct item item_t;
struct item{
    char name;
    int price;
    int quantity;
    item_t *left;
    item_t *right;
};
```

The idea is to prompt a user to enter the above attributes, and then add the entered item to a node. This is what I've written so far:

```
item_t *root = NULL;
item_t *current_leaf = NULL;

void prompt_user(){
    /*
    In here contains the code that prompts the user for the item attributes
    and stores it in a variable called input
    */
    insert_node(input);
}

void insert_node(char *input){
    /*If tree doesnt have a root...*/
    if (root == NULL){

        /*Create one...*/
        *root = create_node(input);
    }

    else{
        item_t *cursor = root;
        item_t *prev = NULL;
        int is_left = 0;
        int comparison;

        while(cursor != NULL){

            /*comparison will be 1 is the key of input is less than the key   
            of the cursor, and 2 otherwise...*/
            comparison = compare(input, cursor);
            prev = cursor;

            if(comparison == 1){
                is_left = 1;
                cursor = cursor->left;
            }
            else if (comparison == 2){
                is_left = 0;
                cursor = cursor->right;
            }
        }

        if(is_left){
            *prev->left = create_node(input);
            current_leaf = prev->left;
        }
        else{
            *prev->right = create_node(input);
            current_leaf = prev->right;
        }
    }
}

item_t create_node(char *input){

    item_t *new_node = (item_t*)malloc(sizeof(item_t));

    if (new_node == NULL){
        printf("Out of memory. Shutting down.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*Add data to the node...*/
    update_item(input, new_node);

    new_node->left = NULL;
    new_node->right = NULL;

    current_leaf = new_node;

    return *new_node;
}
```

I want `root` to always be pointing to the first item ever entered, and `current_leaf` to be pointing to the last item processed. `compare` returns 1 if the item being processed (`input`) is less than the last processed item (`current_leaf`). `update_item` is what sets the data for the new nodes (leaves).

The above isn't fully complete, but it's what I'm up to at the moment. I'm struggling to work out how to write `add_node` and how to keep `current_leaf` updated correctly.

EDIT: revised my code

Comment: BTW: recursion is not required for an `add` function into a binary tree. IMHO an interative method is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @MichaelWalz how else do you suggest I can do it?

Comment: Start at the root. If the item to be inserted is smaller move to the left node, else move tot the right node. Repeat this until you stumble upon a NULL pointer and this is the place where your new node goes. This is purely iterative. BTW: on the other hand _traversing_ your tree is easiest done in a recursive way.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I've updated my code. Does that look better? At the moment I have no way of testing the code

Comment: @laurisvr: the question is about C and not C++

Answer (score 0):

It is an example of BST. Structure of the tree is:

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
}node;
```

Letting root global is not a good idea, so it is better to declare it inside `main()` and the `insert()` will be called from main like this:

```
int main()
{
    int n,data;
    node *root=NULL;
    printf("How many elements? ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
         scanf("%d",&data);
         insert(&root,data);
    }
    inorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code for insertion and traversing a binary tree-

```
void insert(node **root, int data)
{
    node *n1,*temp;
    n1=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    n1->data=data;
    n1->left=n1->right=NULL;
    if(!(*root))
    {
        (*root)=n1;
        //printf("Node inserted\n");
        return;
    }
    temp=*root;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data<temp->data)
        {
            //printf("To the right");
            if(temp->right==NULL)
            {
                temp->right=n1;
                break;
            }
            else
                temp=temp->right;
        }
        else if(temp->data>=n1->data)
        {
            if(temp->left==NULL)
            {
                temp->left=n1;
                break;
            }
            else
                temp=temp->left;
        }
    }
    //printf("Inserted\n");
}

void inorder(node *root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return;
    inorder(root->left);
    printf("item: %d",root->data);
    inorder(root->right);
}
```

> The searching will be same almost same logic as insert, please develop it yourself.